# Swift replace first character in string

Tags: ios, swift

A very simple question, how do I replace the first character of a string. I'm probably doing something totally wrong, but I simply can't get it to work.

I have tried this: `var query = url.query!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "?", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))`

But it gives me the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' with an argument list of type '(String, withString: String, options: NSStringCompareOptions, range: NSRange)'

When I remove the NSMakeRange and change it to nil, it works, but it replaces all the &'s in the string.

Comment: When you pass `nil` as the `range`, of course it will replace all the `&` characters as you are using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`.

Comment: I get that, I just wanted to tell that I got that working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var s = "123456"

let s2 = s.replacingCharacters(in: ...s.startIndex, with: "a")

s2 // "a23456"
```

Comment: Just a note that it would crash the app if the string is empty

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 4 or later**

```
let string = "&whatever"
let output = "?" + string.dropFirst()
```

mutating the string

```
var string = "&whatever"
if !string.isEmpty {
    string.replaceSubrange(...string.startIndex, with: "?")
    print(string)  // "?whatever\n"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let range = Range(start: query.startIndex, end: query.startIndex.successor())
query.replaceRange(range, with: "?")
```

or shorter

```
let s = query.startIndex
query.replaceRange(s...s, with: "?")
```

This is a bit different from Objective-C - but we will get used to it I guess ;-).

If you are uncomfortable with this, you can always drop back to the old `NSString` APIs:

```
let newQuery = (query as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(
  NSMakeRange(0,1), withString: "?") // as String not necessary
```

Comment: `let i = query.startIndex; query.replaceRange(i...i, with: "?")`

Comment: Thanks - I included that in my answer.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `NSMakeRange(0,1)` and `newQuery` will be `String` even if you don't do the `as String` cast.  That surprised me as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.0

```
let inputString = "!Hello"
let outputString = String(inputString.dropFirst())
```

**Answer**

```
outputString = "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an NSRange value, where a Range object is expected.
When using Swift strings, you have to use

```
Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end: advance(str.startIndex, 1))
```

Comment: I'm now using: var query = url.query!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "?", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: url.query!.startIndex, end: advance(url.query!.startIndex, 1))) but it still hasn't replaced the first character. Am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 you can do something like this:-

```
let inputString = "!Hello"
let outputString = String(inputString.characters.dropFirst())

//Answer
outputString = "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0

```
extension String
{
    func replace_fromStart(str:String , endIndex:Int , With:String) -> String {
        var strReplaced = str ;
        let start = str.startIndex;
        let end = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: endIndex);
        strReplaced = str.replacingCharacters(in: start..<end, with: With) ;
        return strReplaced;
    }
}
```

use it any where

```
MY_String.replace_fromStart(str: MY_String, endIndex: 10, With: "**********")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another answer**

Use **suffix**

```swift
var s = "1234567"
var transform = "?" + s.suffix(max(s.count - 1, 0))
transform // "?234567"
```